# partial differentiation in a geodesic problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm trying to understand the example (which is given in a textbook):

> Determine  $$y\in\{f\in C^2[0,1]:\ f(0)=0,\ f(1)=1\}$$
>
> such that $J(y)=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}dx$ is minimum.

From a theorem, we know $y$ has to satisfy the following differential equation:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0.$$

where $f(x,y(x),y'(x))=\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}$.

But it's unclear to me how to find $\partial f/\partial y'$ and $\partial f/\partial y$. I'm not really sure what these partial derivatives even mean. The work in the textbook gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}=\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$

and that "sorta" makes sense if we treat $y$ and $y'$ as real variables... but they're not? Maybe this is super basic stuff from multivariable calculus, but I haven't done that in years.

Comment: The theorem is called "Euler-Lagrange equation" in the field of "calculus of variations".  I'm trying to make sense of it too.  You'll find your example problem in here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have instead

$$
\sqrt{\alpha y^2+\beta y y'+\gamma y'^2}\equiv\sqrt{\alpha u^2+\beta u v+\gamma v^2} = f(u,v)
$$

Regarding the partial derivative $u$ and $v$ are considered as independent so

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2\alpha u+\beta v}{\sqrt{\alpha u^2+\beta u v+\gamma v^2}}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2\gamma v+\beta u}{\sqrt{\alpha u^2+\beta u v+\gamma v^2}}
$$

and finally

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{2\gamma y'+\beta y}{\sqrt{\alpha y^2+\beta y y'+\gamma y'^2}}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2\alpha y+\beta y'}{\sqrt{\alpha y^2+\beta y y'+\gamma y'^2}}
$$

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$? If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, then I have no problems with taking partial derivatives. The confusion has to do with the symbolism $\partial f/\partial y$ which says we take a partial derivative with respect to a function. What does that mean? It's not really clear to me why we can treat $y$ as a real variable. ALSO: $y(x)$ is a function used to define $f$, so shouldn't we be using the chain rule?

Comment: Formally is is equivalent. You can develop it like Euler himself using lot of formulas. This is a short hand operational rule. As for instance when you intend to find the implicit derivative for $f(y(x),x) = 0$ The short hand procedure is to do $y' = -\frac{f_x}{f_y}$. The result is the same but with less algebraic effort.

Answer (score 0):

They *are* variables when you differentiate with respect to them. Maybe if you write 
$$f(x,y,y') = \sqrt{1+(y')^2}$$
then it is more clear that ${\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0}$ and by the chain rule ${\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} = \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}}.$

If you wanted to differentiate with respect to $x$, instead, then you should consider that $y'$ depends on $x$.

Comment: To be clear, the Lagrangian is a function $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. So writing $f(x,y,y')$ is kinda misleading since $y$ and $y'$ are functions. That's why this is confusing: the notation $\partial f/\partial y$ suggests we are differentiating "with respect to a function".

Comment: Yours is not a problem related to Lagrangians, it is just a problem on the operation of differentiation. When you have a function $f(x,y(x),y'(x))$ you can make sense of four different types of derivatives: $\partial/\partial x$, $\partial/\partial y$, $\partial/\partial y'$ and $d/dx$. The first three have the meaning of 'differentiating with respect to the first/second/third variable respectively', whereas the fourth is the total derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. In your problem, you are using differentiation with respect to second and third variable.